# Proving or disproving this matrix $V$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Here is a question on the invertibility of a special structured matrix:

**Notations:** Let us take $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ bins and $d\in \mathbb{N}^*$ balls. Denote the set $B = \{\alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^m\}$ to be all possible choices for putting $d$ balls into $n$ bins, such as

$$\alpha^1 = (d,0,\ldots, 0), ~ \alpha^2 = (0,d,\ldots, 0), \ldots$$

Let us define the matrix $V$ as:

$$V = \begin{bmatrix}
(\alpha^1)^{\alpha^1} & \cdots & (\alpha^1)^{\alpha^m}\\
(\alpha^2)^{\alpha^1} & \cdots & (\alpha^2)^{\alpha^m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
(\alpha^m)^{\alpha^1} & \cdots & (\alpha^m)^{\alpha^m}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where the notation $(\alpha^i)^{\alpha^j} = \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\alpha^i_k)^{\alpha^j_k}$ (under assumption that $0^0=1$, and $\alpha^i_k$ indicates the $k$th element of $\alpha^i$).

**Question:** "**is the matrix $V$ invertible?**"

I have tested several examples, and it seems that $V$ is always invertible, but I have no idea how to prove it or find a counterexample.

Here are two facts I understood:

1. all diagonal elements are strictly positives, so the trace of $V$ is strictly positive.
2. the matrix $V$ is not symmetric.

Can anyone help prove or disprove the invertibility of $V$? Thanks a lot in advance for sharing any idea, any useful discussion and remark.

---

For a better understanding of the problem, I add here an example:

**Example:** Let $n=3$ and $d=2$, then we have all possible choices for putting $2$ balls into $3$ bins as:

$$B = \{(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}.$$

The elements in the first row of the matrix $V$ are computed as:

$$(\alpha^1)^{\alpha^1} = (2,0,0)^{(2,0,0)} = 2^2\times 0^0\times 0^0 = 4,$$

$$(\alpha^1)^{\alpha^2} = (2,0,0)^{(0,2,0)} = 2^0\times 0^2\times 0^0 = 0,$$

and so on.

Thus, we have the matrix $V$ as:

$$V = \begin{bmatrix}
4&0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&4&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&4&0&0&0\\
    1&1&0&1&0&0\\
    1&0&1&0&1&0\\
    0&1&1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is clearly invertible.

**Remarks:**

1. Note that, the matrix $V$ is not always triangular. as an example, for n=3, d=3, the element $$(2,1,0)^{(1,2,0)} = 2^1\times 1^2 \times 0^0 = 2,$$ and $$(1,2,0)^{(2,1,0)} = 1^2\times 2^1 \times 0^0 = 2$$
   which are both non-zeros, thus $V$ will be never invertible in this case.
2. When the elements $(\alpha^i)^{\alpha^j}$ and $(\alpha^j)^{\alpha^i}$  (with $i\neq j$) are non-zeros, they may not be equal.
   E.g., n=4, d=8, we have
   $$(1,1,2,4)^{(2,2,2,2)} = 64$$
   but
   $$(2,2,2,2)^{(1,1,2,4)} = 256.$$

As a conclusion: "the matrix $V$ is neither triangular nor symmetric in general."

Comment: How are you defining $0^0$ in this case? That is normally undefined ($lim_{x -> 0} x^x$ does not exist as it is different depending on which side you approach it from )

Comment: @cmitch: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero. $0^0$ is always taken as $1$ in combinatorics, because of its interpretation as the number of mappings from the empty set to itself.

Comment: @cmitch Exactly as Rob's remark, $0^0=1$ and $0^k=0$ if $k>0$.

Comment: Sorry what exactly is meant by $\alpha_k^i$? Could you also give an example of the matrix for some small $n$ and $d$? Thanks!

Comment: @paulinho Of course, here is an example: Let n=3, d=2, then we have $B = \{(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$. The elements of $B$ are $\alpha^i, i=1,\ldots,6$. Here we have $m=6$ possible choices to put 2 balls into 3 bins.

Comment: BTW: $\alpha^i_k$ is the $k$-th element of $\alpha^i$, e.g., $\alpha^1_1=2$ and $\alpha^5_3=1$ etc. Note that I have not mentioned how to order all $\alpha^i, i=1,\ldots,m$, but I don't think the order is important for the invertibility of the matrix $V$ since if the matrix is invertible for one order, then exchange the order of $\alpha^i$ means exchange the rows and columns of $V$ which is obviously invertible as well.